# NSURLConnection object goes nil

Tags: ios

Would like to know why `conndetailing = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];` goes nil

```
//enter code here
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.myscript.php"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[post release];

//conndetailing goes nil and due to which app crashes
conndetailing = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
[conndetailing scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[conndetailing start];
[request release];
responseDatadetailing=[[NSMutableData data] retain];
```

Comment: Can you show where you declare the variable `conndetailing` in your code?

Comment: @Gavin - It is added in the interface file

Comment: Add the actual code showing it. Edit your question to include a code block showing the actual declaration.

Comment: @Nexttric Also, can you confirm when it's `nil`? Immediately after calling `initWithRequest`? Or are you checking at some later point? Also, have you implemented a `connection:didFailWithError:` which would show you the error, if any?

Comment: @ Rob -I had executed the code using the debug mode and found that initialization to conndetailing is not working, the variable says nil